# Determine Which Side of Rectangle Was Hit

Tags: java, android, graphics, collision-detection, rect

So I have a circle moving towards a rectangle on screen in my Android game. Each has a bounding box with left, top, right, bottom values that match their screen coordinates. I determine if there was a collision using the `RectF.intersects(RectF one, RectF two)` method. Now my problem is to determine which side the collision occurs on. I have done some searching around and every answer just confuses me. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait, you are drawing a circle and a rect, and you checking intersections on two rects?

Why not draw a circle and a rect on the canvas, and measure the distance between each edge of the rect and the center of the circle.  If any of those 4 distances < radius of circle, you'll know which edge was hit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance

dx = p1.x - p2.x
dy = p2.y - p2.y

Math.sqrt(math.pow(dx, 2) + math.pow(dy, 2))

cant figure out formatting in this box, good luck.